"Lifetime Use" Software
I purchased a software suite from a well-known company that was advertised as "Lifetime Use." After not using it for some time, I tried installing them and my key wasn't accepted. I had to email them to get new links. At the end of their email, they told me the license was for installing on only one computer, and if I wanted to ever install them agian, I'd have to pay. Nobody keeps the same computer for life, so I think this B.S.
Your thoughts?

Read the license.

Apparently they interpret it as "lifetime of your computer." How the courts will read it depends on the jurisdiction.

It is pretty much irrelevant what it is "advertised as". There is a contract you signed (or accepted in other forms). What does that say?

There was no contract. It was simply purchased from an online software store.

@TESLA you paid money and got a licence - that's a contract.

Read your contract
When you purchased the software from the online store, you entered a contract in the form of a licence agreement. It will set out what you can and can't do with the software, including defining what "Lifetime Use" means.
False advertising
I agree that the general understanding of "Lifetime Use" means your lifetime (or the company's if that's shorter). If the contract has a different definition, then that may be unlawful, false advertising, but it doesn't change the contract.
If you were induced to enter the contract due to the misrepresentation and that misrepresentation is material (which it probably is), you are entitled to void the contract and get your money back; you are not entitled to change it.
