What happens to a lifetime license/plan after the servers shut down?
A way for new startups to attract customers is to sell lifetime licenses instead of a monthly subscription. In the long-term it'll be a burden for the startup to keep up with the lifetime customers, but it's also a risk for the customers to spend a lot upfront on a lifetime license because most startups fail.
But how much risk lies on the customer? If someone bought a lifetime license for $50 when the monthly subscription is only $10 (5x the price), but the startup shuts down (servers offline) after only 2 months, would the startup owner face any legal consequences? Or is it solely the buyer that has to eat it up?

Closed question, but the answers are accurate https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/102300/lifetime-use-software

Read the contract
In a well-drafted contract, it is unlikely that a "lifetime" contract is actually a perpetual contract. One would expect that the contract will contain circumstances or mechanisms whereby one party or the other can end it. If so, then providing the contract was terminated in accordance with those terms, that's the end of the matter.
Further, "lifetime" should be defined—it may well be the lifetime of the service or the client, whichever is shorter. A host of issues, both in contract and consumer law, would mean that the service would need to be provided for a reasonable time.
Implied terms
Even if the contract is, on its face, perpetual, it's important to note that the courts have, on occasion, implied a term allowing termination on reasonable notice. This legal oversight provides reassurance that even seemingly perpetual contracts can be subject to termination.
However, a "lifetime" contract is not strictly speaking a perpetual contract as there is an end date-it's just an indeterminate end date. I don't know of any cases where this has come up and whether this would affect the outcome.
Breach
The company (or the user) can just breach to contract.
The aggrieved party can sue for damages, or if the contract contains a binding arbitration clause, arbitrate for damages. The loss suffered would need to be substantial enough to justify the time and cost that this would involve.
Of course, this is the same risk you face whenever you contract with someone.
Insolvency
There are a lot of different nuances, but, in general, an insolvent entity will breach its contracts. They will also not have any money to pay damages for those breaches.

generally the terms in "lifetime" contracts are set as "until the server shuts down"
